# Dynamic Pivot without aggregate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 columns in a table and I want to create a dynamic Pivot query.

The SKU and BrandId columns is the "Distinct" side, and the Barcode column should expand side.

**Note:**
The Barcode column should be dynamic because there is unknown Barcodes for every SKU+BrandId.

| SKU | BrandId | Barcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 1 | 987 |
| 1 | 1 | 852 |
| 1 | 2 | 951 |
| 1 | 2 | 753 |
| 2 | 1 | 926 |
| 2 | 1 | 364 |
| 2 | 2 | 854 |
| 2 | 2 | 256 |
| 2 | 2 | 351 |
| 2 | 2 | 157 |
| 2 | 3 | 976 |

Expecting this result:

| SKU | BrandId | Barcode1 | Barcode2 | Barcode3 | Barcode4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 | 987 | 852 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 951 | 753 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 | 926 | 364 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | 854 | 256 | 351 | 157 |
| 2 | 3 | 976 |  |  |  |

Comment: Any given query always produces a result set with a fixed "shape" - the *number* of columns, their names and types. You either have to construct the query on the fly (i.e. dynamic SQL), which inevitably means having to query the data twice, first to find the columns then to do the query - or leave the pivot transformation to a higher level *formatting* tool, rather than trying to do it in the database.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of possible `barcode` columns that there could be? If so you can do this statically using `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the concept is to build a dynamic pivot query as follow

```
 CREATE TABLE #t (sku nvarchar(5), brandid nvarchar(5), barcode nvarchar(50) )
truncate table #t
INSERT INTO #t VALUES 
    (1,1,150),
    (1,1,140),
    (1,1,111),
    (1,2,1234),
    (1,2,145),
    (2,1,345),
    (2,1,532),
    (2,2,875),
    (2,2,1237),
    (3,1,566)

select *,'Barcode'+CONVERT (nvarchar(50),ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by sku, brandid order by sku)) rn from #t   


DECLARE @colName AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @pivotQ AS NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @colName = ISNULL(@colName + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(rn) 
FROM (select DISTINCT 'Barcode'+CONVERT (nvarchar(50),ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by sku, brandid order by sku)) rn from #t  
) AS Labels ORDER BY rn


SET @pivotQ = N'
SELECT sku,   brandid, '+@colName+'
FROM  
(
  SELECT sku,   brandid , barcode , ''Barcode''+CONVERT (nvarchar(50),ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by sku, brandid order by sku)) rn
  FROM #t
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(barcode)  
  FOR rn IN ('+@colName+')  
) AS PivotTable; 
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @pivotQ
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you do not go down the dynamic query route, as it can be difficult to code, and vulnerable to SQL injection.

Instead just hard-code the maximum possible `Barcode` columns in a normal conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  t.Sku,
  t.BrandId,
  Barcode1 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode2 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 2 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode3 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 3 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode4 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 4 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode5 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 5 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode6 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 6 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode7 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 7 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode8 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 8 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode9 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 9 THEN t.Barcode END),
  Barcode10 = MAX(CASE WHEN t.rn = 10 THEN t.Barcode END)
FROM  
(
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Sku, t.BrandId ORDER BY t.Barcode)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
  t.Sku,
  t.BrandId;
```